# Google Sheets - Make a tab change not visible to other users

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to work on a google sheet where one Tab will be an entry form and another will be a database. I need the form to be used by multiple users. Currently the Form tab displays all changes to other users so multiple users cannot use it at the same time.

Is there a way to allow 1 user to see their own entries and a 2nd user to see different entries. When they press my button it should record their individual entries on the database tab.

I cannot use Google Forms for this project due to the complexity of the form and the need for cascading drop-down lists and dynamically available information on the form.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching extensively, the answer to my question is that there does not seem to be a good way of doing this.

My final approach was to create a tab for each user with the calculations, cascading dropdowns, and buttons/scripts that affected their specific sheet and recorded data on the database tab based on their specific sheet.

Hopefully, this helps the next guy who is searching for this answer. If anyone has found a way to solve this, let me know so I can test and give you credit for solving what I could not.